# How to manage country/state/city in single picker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, uipickerview, picker

How would one manage country/state/city value using single picker Objective-C?

When I try it it crashes on index change.  It works city city and state, but issue with city. What library would work better?

See my code below

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{
     self.txtOfficeLocation.text = self.provinceArray[row]; 
     for (int i = 0; i < self.provinceKeyValueDic.count; i++) {
        if ([self.provinceKeyValueDic.allKeys[i] isEqualToString:self.provinceArray[row]]){
                 provinceID = [[self.provinceKeyValueDic.allValues[i]valueForKey:@"id"]in‌​tegerValue]; NSLog(@"province key :%d", provinceID); 
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Show your code, if anything you tried?

Comment: - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{


    self.txtOfficeLocation.text = self.provinceArray[row];


    for (int i = 0; i < self.provinceKeyValueDic.count; i++) {


        if ([self.provinceKeyValueDic.allKeys[i] 
isEqualToString:self.provinceArray[row]]) {

            provinceID =[[self.provinceKeyValueDic.allValues[i]valueForKey:@"id"]integerValue];

            NSLog(@"province key :%d", provinceID);


        }


    }
}

on pickerview done button api call

Answer (score 2):

I know you have asked for Objective-C code, but here's a swift example - the key elements are easy to translate.

I don't know how you have set up your data, but I created some like this

```
    struct StateData
{
    var state : String
    var city : [String] = []
}

struct CountryData
{
    var country : String
    var state : [StateData] = []
}

var pickerData : [CountryData] = []
```

You can populate it any way you like

```
    var stateData = CountryData(country: "UK", state: [StateData(state: "Midlothian", city: ["Edinburgh", "Bathgate", "Livingston"])])
    stateData.state.append(StateData(state: "Strathclyde", city: ["Glasgow", "Prestwick", "Lanark"]))
    pickerData.append(stateData)

    stateData = CountryData(country: "USA", state: [StateData(state: "Alabama", city: ["Montgomery", "Birmingham"])])
    stateData.state.append(StateData(state: "Alaska", city: ["Juneau", "Anchorage"]))
    stateData.state.append(StateData(state: "Arizona", city: ["Phoenix", "Another city", "City 3"]))
    pickerData.append(stateData)
```

I think the key thing is to keep track of what you have selected

```
var countrySelected : Int   = 0
var stateSelected : Int     = 0
var citySelected : Int      = 0
```

The pickerView methods need to look something like this

```
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
{
    return 3 // country, state, city
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
{
    switch component
    {
    case 0: // country
        return pickerData.count

    case 1: // state
        return pickerData[countrySelected].state.count

    case 2: // city
        return pickerData[countrySelected].state[stateSelected].city.count

    default:
        return 0
    }
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
{
    switch component
    {
    case 0: // country
        return pickerData[row].country

    case 1: // state
        return pickerData[countrySelected].state[row].state

    case 2: // city
        return pickerData[countrySelected].state[stateSelected].city[row]

    default:
        return ""
    }
}
```

The interesting bit is to make sure that when you change country, or change state, that you don't end up with a state or city index that points to a value that doesn't exist in your new display - as when you go from having selected the third city in one state and move to a state with only two cities.  That will generate the out of bounds errors that you have been seeing.  You can fix it like this

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
{

    switch component {
    case 0: // country
        countrySelected = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        stateSelected = 0
        citySelected = 0

        pickerView.reloadComponent(1)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 1, animated: true)
        pickerView.reloadComponent(2)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 2, animated: true)

    case 1: // country
        stateSelected = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)
        citySelected = 0

        pickerView.reloadComponent(2)
        pickerView.selectRow(0, inComponent: 2, animated: true)

    case 2: // country
        citySelected = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 2)

    default:
        break
    }

    print("\(pickerData[countrySelected].country), \(pickerData[countrySelected].state[stateSelected].state), \(pickerData[countrySelected].state[stateSelected].city[citySelected])")
}
```